# How to calculate the sum of numbers in one file and print the result into another file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

We have an input text file that contains 2 integers a and b. Calculate the 2 numbers just entered and print the value of the sum into the output text file.
Here is what I've tried so far:

```
x= open ("input.txt", "r")
Sum=[]
z = x.readlines()
for i in z:
if i.isdigit():
    Sum += (z)
x.close()
y= open ("output.txt", "w")
y.write(str(Sum))
y.close()
```

Comment: You need to initialize `Sum = 0` and use `Sum += int(z)`

Comment: Did this fail? What went wrong? The indentation under the `for` is incorrect (but that could just be a problem posting the code). Include sample input, expected output and any error messages you get on the way.

Comment: Notice an answer where someone assumes the input is something like "1 + 1"? That's what happens when you don't tell us what the input format is. People start guessing. Please make this an answerable question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines you're reading from the input file are strings so you need to convert them to ints. Also, each line will have a newline character '\n' at the end which will need to be removed before you can successfully convert each line to an int.

There are also several other issues with your code example. Sum is a list, but aren't you trying to add each int from input.txt? Also `if i.isdigit()` is not indented. try, except can be used instead though.

```
x = open("input.txt", "r")
Sum = 0
z = x.readlines()
for i in z:
    try:
        Sum += int(i.strip())
    except ValueError:
        pass

x.close()
y= open ("output.txt", "w")
y.write(str(Sum))
y.close()
```

Comment: You can(should) omit `.readlines()` and use `for i in x:`. Also better to use `i.rstrip()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `eval()` function to make it easier...

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as inp:
        out.write(str(eval(inp.read())))
```

`input.txt`:

```
1 + 1
```

`output.txt`

```
2
```

Comment: I don't think that's the format of the input file.

Comment: You can open files in single line `with open('input.txt') as inp, open('output.txt', 'w') as out:`. Also I don't recommend to use `eval()`, it's better to avoid evaluation at all or use `ast.literal_eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the import function to import this code into another file as a module. In the original code file, you can use a function under which the code will be under of. Then whenever you call that function in the output file, you will get the output.